# drop caches linux for kernel < 2.6.16

Tags: linux

what is the equivalent command for this one:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

but for kernels older than 2.6.16 ?

I have 2.6.12 kernel

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

How about the same one. If I am not grossly mistaken or can't remember things now (just woke up and still in sleep). it should be the same. The command you mentioned is the standard way to drop caches.

Comment: Only it was added in 2.6.16...

Comment: Agreed.  http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html